# How to change the value in Constructor ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that the code is working correctly

I would like to be able to change the value `val: 'yolo'` by either a component from another page or direct by my database

Do you have an idea, how to fix this? Neff

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT + '/api';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {

  data: [],
 };
 this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
 this.state = {currentPosition: 0, totalLength: 3, val: 'yolo'}
}
getRandom = async () => {

const res = await axios.get(
  entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
)
this.setState({ data: res.data })
}

componentDidMount() {
this.getRandom()
}

clickHandler(){ 
this.setState({currentPosition: (this.state.currentPosition + 1)%this.state.totalLength})
}
render() {
 return (
  <div >
    <button onClick={this.clickHandler} >Move to the Right</button>
    {
      Array.from(
        {length: this.state.totalLength},
        (_,i) => (
          <div key={i} className="slot">
            <p>{i === this.state.currentPosition ? this.state.val : null}</p>
          </div>
        )
      )
    }
  </div>
 )}
 }

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*direct by my database*"?

Comment: @Chris
 a bit like a map  {datass.items} just take the value

Comment: you need redux.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can change the value of Yolo similar way as you are getting data from the server.
as for changing it from another component , you can do it by either getting it as a props from its parent component where you use this component

```
<App  yoloVal = {"yoloValue"}/>
```

and you can receive it in props either when it mounts or when it updates

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
    yolo : this.props.yoloVal
  }
}
```

or when it updates

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  if(this.props.yoloVal !== prevProps.yoloVal){    
    this.setState({
      yolo : this.props.yoloVal
    }
  } 
}
```

you can also get this value from a child in the App by passing it a method
write a method in the App Component

```
setYoloValue(val){
   this.setState({
      yolo : val
   }
}
```

now pass this method in render method of App to a child component

```
return (
<ChildComponent setYoloValue = {this.setYoloValue.bind(this)}
)
```

we are using bind so when this method is called the context remains of the parent instead of the caller(child component)

now you can use this method anywhere in the child to set the value of Yolo on parent

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.setYoloValue("new Yolo Value by child")
  }
}
```

Now as for passing data between siblings , you can give the data by using the above two methods , first have a common parent , pass the data to parent by using second method then pass that data parent received to the other children as the first method. that is how you can acheive communication between siblings components.
as for setting the value from any other component in the app that is not directly related to you component , you need Redux or similar that does the job for you by keeping the values in a common store and components listen to that store and receive the update when the value in the store updates.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to change the value val: 'yolo'
>
> 1.by either a component,
>
> 2.from another page
>
> 3.or direct by my database

i'm actually surprised by the following piece of code, and not even sure, it 's a valid one. you are initializing this.state twice inside your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 --> this.state = {

  data: [],
 };
 this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
 --> this.state = {currentPosition: 0, totalLength: 3, val: 'yolo'}
}
```

you initialize your entire variables inside your constructor..

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  data: [],
  currentPosition: 0,
  totalLength: 3,
  val: 'yolo',
 };
 this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
}
```

idea is to pass a function(prevState) as a callback to update the local state so as to escape batching.

```
getRandom = async () => {
 const res = await axios.get(
  entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
 )
 this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  ...prevState,
  data: res.data,
 }))
}
```

i'm not sure this will work as you expected..

```
clickHandler(){ 
this.setState({currentPosition: (this.state.currentPosition + 1)%this.state.totalLength})
}
```

since you are doing a division, it's good to Math.floor or ceil(you need to find whichever value meets your requirement.)

//1. by a component..

```
handleValChange(val) => {
 this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  val,
 }))
}
//now u can pass it to a child component.

render() {
 const { handleValChange } = this

 return (
  <div>
   <...rest of the div.../>
   <ChildComponent {...{ handleValChange }} />
  </div>
 ) 
}
```

2. from another page.

from another page means, probable a diffrent route. in such cases u need to update this globally(redux, mobx etc..) and the value should also live globally not locally. u can pass id's and stuff via url but function, not possible.

3. direct by db.

this is where u make an api call and based on the response u update the state. that means, it's time to extract your application into a global state(redux, mobx etc..)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {

  data: [],
 };
 this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)
 this.state = {currentPosition: 0, totalLength: 3, val: 'yolo'}
```

You should not have two states in one constructor. Change it to one state:

```
this.state {
    data: [],
    currentPosition: 0,
    totalLength: 3,
    val: 'yolo',
}
```

As for changing the value from another component, there are two easy solutions.

1) Using Redux to handle state, instead of local state, probably the best solution.

2) Use a callback function that call setState in that component, and pass it to the other component, if it is a child of this component.

```
const myCallbackFunction(value: string) {
    this.setState({ val: value })
}
```